# How to open a single project like Behance with nuxt,js?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am working on a project using NUXT.JS where i want to open a project within a same page overlay somethink like [behance](https://www.behance.net/gallery/78343551/Personal-Collection?tracking_source=best_of_behance_big_covers). in other words when i click on a project i want to stop page redirection and open a project there in same place with a route but when someone comes to that route it will be a separate page.

I tried Nuxt nested routes with nuxt-child but didn't work or i didn't understand.

**This is my structure**
[image]

This is my project strucure

Answer (score 0):

You could create a component and import it in your index page as a modal window (so it gives the content of a modal-component), and also create a page where you import the same component as page content.

This way you can have it in the overlay and also as a separate page.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried but just maybe, you could make a "group page" with two routes (two pages), different, one with params other without, one with modal other without.
So  on the route with the params (e.g. Id of a single product) the modal pops up when route is loaded, and on the route without (basically other page, but same in design) there's no modal just a grid of "products".

The only thing that comes to my mind, how do you make same page different routes in Nuxt ???